# Adding optimizations decrease the accuracy, precision, f1 of classifier algorithms

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, text-classification

I want to build an algorithm that classifies text: ham or spam; I have the train/test data for each category of text. (my train data has for each category `8000 sentences`, and for test each category contains `2000 sentences`)

X_train looks like this `['please, call me asap!', 'watch out the new sales!', 'hello jim can we talk?', 'only today you can buy this', 'don't miss our offer!']`

y_train looks like this `[1 0 1 0 0]` where 1 = ham, 0 = spam

the same with X_test and y_test.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
# classifier can be LogisticRegression, MultinomialNB, RandomForest, DecisionTree
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                     ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                     ('clf', classifier),
                    ])
model = text_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict = model.predict(X_test)
```

And these are the parameters that I measure:

```
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict))
print(f1_score(y_test, y_predict, average="weighted"))
print(recall_score(y_test, y_predict, pos_label=1, average="binary"))
print(precision_score(y_test, y_predict, average="weighted"))
```

If I don't use any optimization (`remove stop words, remove punctuation, stem words, lemmatize words`) I obtain results around 95% each parameter. If I use those optimizations, the accuracy, f1 score and precision decrease drastically to 50-60%. The recall function stays the same at 95%.

Why is this happening? Where am I mistaking? Did I calculate right those parameters? Or this is a normal behavior?

Comment: Usually "optimization" means trading one thing for another, e.g.  accuracy for speed of training. Were you expecting something for nothing?

Comment: If I call them `features` will you try to told me why this behavior?

Comment: I would try adding the optimizations one at a time, to see what their effects are individually.  If there's a particular one that's causing this behavior, take a look at what it's doing.

Comment: I added them one after another, the same results I obtained. Each of them will decrease those parameters.

Comment: They won't increase the accuracy of `DummyClassifier` from `sklearn` either. Whatever I do, it will stay at 48-50%.

Comment: So halving your training set might be an "optimization" you could do - would that improve or reduce the quality of the results? Look at what you're doing - perhaps all the spam has little/no punctuation so removing punctuation from the training set makes the ham look more like spam. Perhaps stop words are used in ham not spam, so removing them eliminates them as a possibility of producing better results. And so on. You'll have to look at _your_ data in the light of the _features_ _you_ are selecting to get an answer, because the features _you_ are selecting are affecting _your_ results.

Comment: Please add the complete code (with and without optimization) with dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out what is wrong: underfitting. I performed cross-validation

`scores = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')`

and now everything is fine, I obtain the results I was expecting.